# How to binding listviewitem?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want. When I click on the listview, the textblock below will display the text of the selected item?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="lol">
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="One"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Two"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Three"/>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text,ElementName=lol.SelectedItem}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the binding you need:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content.Text, ElementName=lol}"/>
```

Be aware, that in your case `SelectedItem` is a `ListViewItem` and it's content is a `TextBlock`.

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger might be required as well.

Comment: @just-my-name What is the source property that you expect `TextBlock.Text`, which is read-only, to write to?